# Python Tensorflow - Data augmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-augmentation

**My Goal:**

I want to enlarge my dataset (consisting of ~20000 photos) with data augmentation.

**Maybe the solution?**

I'm using ResNet50 and I have found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation) that this may be the way to do it:

```
def prepare(ds, shuffle=False, augment=False):
  if shuffle:
    ds = ds.shuffle(1000)

  # Batch all datasets.
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size)

  # Use data augmentation only on the training set.
  if augment:
    ds = ds.map(lambda x, y: (data_augmentation(x, training=True), y), 
                num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

  # Use buffered prefetching on all datasets.
  return ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)


train_ds = prepare(train_ds, shuffle=True, augment=True)
val_ds = prepare(val_ds)
```

But this gives me an error:

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'random_flip' (type RandomFlip).

Image augmentation layers are expecting inputs to be rank 3 (HWC) or 4D (NHWC) tensors. Got shape: (None, None, 180, 180, 3)

Call arguments received by layer 'random_flip' (type RandomFlip):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, 180, 180, 3), dtype=float32)
  • training=True
```

**Background:**

I want to enlarge the dataset, not to randomly augment some photos, so is this even the right way to do it? If so, how can I specify if I want to enlarge it by 2x or even more? I can do it manually by writing a program that will copy all photos, modify them and save them as new ones, but if there is a better way to do it I'm all for it.

Without the `prepare()` function it works well, but I need to improve its accuracy.

The rest of my code is here: (It is a mashup of stuff I've found, I'm still fairly new to all this)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import PIL
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


DATASET_PATH = "MY_DATASET_PATH"
CLASS_NAMES = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"]

img_height,img_width=180,180
batch_size=32

data_augmentation = tf.keras. Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
  tf.keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.RandomContrast(0.3),
  tf.keras.layers.RandomBrightness(0.3)
])

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  DATASET_PATH,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  DATASET_PATH,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)


AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

def prepare(ds, shuffle=False, augment=False):
  if shuffle:
    ds = ds.shuffle(1000)

  # Batch all datasets.
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size)

  # Use data augmentation only on the training set.
  if augment:
    ds = ds.map(lambda x, y: (data_augmentation(x, training=True), y), 
                num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

  # Use buffered prefetching on all datasets.
  return ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)


train_ds = prepare(train_ds, shuffle=True, augment=True)
val_ds = prepare(val_ds)


resnet_model = Sequential()

pretrained_model= tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False,
                   input_shape=(180,180,3),
                   pooling='avg',classes=len(CLASS_NAMES),
                   weights='imagenet')

for layer in pretrained_model.layers:
        layer.trainable=False

resnet_model.add(pretrained_model)
resnet_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
resnet_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
resnet_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax'))

# resnet_model.summary()

resnet_model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

epochs=5
history = resnet_model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=epochs
)

resnet_model.save("MY_LOCAL_PATH/test.h5", save_format="h5")

fig1 = plt.gcf()
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.axis(ymin=0,ymax=1)
plt.grid()
plt.title('Model Accuracy')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'])
plt.show()

plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.grid()
plt.title('Model Loss')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Remove this line ds = ds.batch(batch_size).

Comment: To elaborate Innat's comment a bite more: You're drawing batches from batches, increasing the dimensions.

Comment: @Innat Thank you! And it is possible to change how much you want to expand the dataset? For example how to make 10 different augmented images from single one?

Comment: For online data augmentation, 10 samples from 1 would change the batch size also, which you may don't want it. But if you consider using offline data augmentation, then it’s doable.